# Better way to break out of while loop? C

Tags: c++, loops

I need to create a singly linked list based on user input which adds to the front of the list and is based upon user input.  I have completed the program, but I am, for some reason, running a blank on one smaller part with the user input here:

```
    while(numInput != -1)
{
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> numInput;
    if(numInput != -1)
    {
        theList->addToHead(numInput);
    }
}
```

I know there is a better way to write this even though it does the correct thing.  If I don't have the IF statement within the while loop, it will add "-1" to the list and I don't want that.  So this code works, but I feel it should be written differently.  I messed around with different loops but cannot think of it right now.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `goto`. Hur hur hur

Comment: I hope there is a way to downvote a comment...(or he is being sarcastic

Comment: @texasbruce The "*hur hur hur*" should be a hint. (or are *you* being sarcastic too?) :-p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could use [`comma operator`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), it will be neat.

```
while(cout << "Enter a number: ", cin >> numInput && numInput != -1)
{
    theList->addToHead(numInput);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `while(cout << "Enter a number: ", cin >> numInput && numInput != -1)` ?

Comment: better to use the `&&` operator here

Answer (score 3):

```
break;
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you meant was:

```
std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
while (std::cin >> numInput && numInput != -1) {
    theList->addToHead(numInput);
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
}
```

Comment: ahhh just needed to move stuff around..I knew it'd be simple and I'm not sure how I forgot that.  Guess I need to do the simple stuff before I have a few beers.  Thanks a lot everyone, always very helpful.